# What does the phrase "shorten pass directness" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "shorten pass directness" mean in the following sentence from a soccer management simulation game?

As a manager, you will get many options to make changes in your strategy. For example, you can shorten pass directness and lower tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author makes an unusual choice of words with both **shorten pass directness** and **lower tempo**.

**Shorten pass directness** means to make shorter passes. This also implies that you would need to make more of them to get to the goal. For example, if Player C is near the goal and player B is midfield, instead of making a long pass from Player A to Player C, you might make a pass from Player A to Player B, and then have Player B pass to Player C to score the goal. That would be an indirect pass from Player A to Player C.

**Lower tempo** means to slow things down, usually in a musical context, but I suppose it has the same meaning when applied to soccer.